# ExpressJs and POST from external source to my income router, how to get data

Tags: express

I'm getting my hands dirty with Node and expressJS, new with Node and ExpressJS, and there something that I can't get right.

There is a service that POST data (json format {}) to my  "income" router, the thing is, a logger helper that check all routers is printing (console.log) the incoming data, but inside the router, I can't get anything (i can't do a console.log for example), not req.body, there is "nothing", just the res.sendStatus(200) that is required for (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push).

Any idea about why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could possibly be some middlewares attached that are actually doing the job, while the router is merely printing the logs. In this case, middleware are attached to be functional well before the code in route gets executed.

Check for app.use or router.post('SOMEPATH',MIDDLEWARE1, MIDDLEWARE2)

ExpressJS's core strength is to modularise the code using middleware.